# Can you use the sum method for both float and int using user input in JAVA?

Tags: java, integer, css-float

So I am working on a project and my code works when I put a float or int in the first input and then add with an int in second input. But if I try to add a int in the first input and a float in the second input it does not work.

For example,
Enter the first number:
34.6
This input is of type float.

Enter the second number:
90
Your answer is: 124.6
The above works.

Below does not work.
Enter the first number:
90

Enter the second number:
34.7

Here is my code:

> import java.util.Scanner;

// Basic Intro/ Refresher for Sums using User Input
public class BasicSums {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // User input 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
    
    
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        int initial = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nEnter the second number: ");
        int second = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + Integer.sum(initial, second));
    
    //Considering the possibility of the user entering a decimal value  
    } else if (input.hasNextFloat()) {
        System.out.println("This input is of type float.\n");
        float first = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        float second = input.nextFloat();   
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + Float.sum(first, second));          
    } 
    
    
    
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if block for `if (input.hasNextInt())` (i.e. the first input is an integer), you only try to read two ints (using `input.nextInt()`), so inputs with decimals will not be accepted for the second number.

One way to fix this is to use `float second = input.nextFloat();` and just use the `+` operator to sum `first` and `second`.

Since integers can be considered real numbers with no fractional part, you can also simply read two floats (or doubles, for higher precision) and add them with the `+` operator.

Comment: So you mean something like this: 
  if (input.hasNextInt()) {
   int initial = input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("\nEnter the second number: ");
   float second = input.nextFloat();
   
   System.out.println("Your answer is: ");System.out.println(initial + second);

Comment: @user21229721 Yes, you could do that.

Comment: @user21229721 It is not necessary, as you can just read two floats directly.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code and thanks to the responses. I decided to stick with floats.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

// Basic Intro/ Refresher for Sums using User Input
public class BasicSums {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // User input 
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        //Using Float to consider possibility of decimal values 
        float first = input.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        float second = input.nextFloat();   
        System.out.println("Your answer is: " + Float.sum(first, second));  
        
        
        }
}
```

This allows for either.